# remove an object from a JSON array that was returned from $.grep()

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I'm searching through an array of json objects:

```
let result = $.grep(jsonObjectArray, matchBothNames);
if (result.length == 1) { // unique match found
   matchFound(result); // do stuff with the result
   jsonObjectArray.remove(result);  // how do I do something like this?
}
```

How can I remove the result of $.grep() from the array it was searching through?

The objects don't have a single unique key/value that I can use.

EDIT:

Here's a sample of the array:

```
[
   {
      "First Name":"John",
      "Last Name":"Smith",
      "Block":"A",
      "Mark":"75%",
      "Student #":7724945
   },
   {
      "First Name":"Jane",
      "Last Name":"Doe",
      "Block":"C,D",
      "Mark":"56%",
      "Student #":7715245
   },
   ...
]
```

Doh, now that I look at it Student Number IS unique.

Comment: Just out of curiosity do you mind sharing what your `jsonObjectArray` looks like !

Comment: added a sample.... a found a unique key.  Haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array#indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [`Array#splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```
let result = $.grep(jsonObjectArray, matchBothNames);
if (result.length == 1) { // unique match found
   matchFound(result); // do stuff with the result
   let index = jsonObjectArray.indexOf(result[0]);
   jsonObjectArray.splice(index,1);  
}
```